# Fragment - Getting view already has a parent error on calling onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I am inflating a fragment from activity at runtime. So, in order to inflate the view of the fragment in the fragment class I called:

```
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_fragment, container);
  }
```

At this moment I get a crash with logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

But if I modify my method as:

```
      @Nullable
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_fragment, null);
      }
```

where I now specify my container as `null`, it works. But what I didn't understand is where did I specify a parent for the view in the code which was crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read from [this link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/) that why and when you pass parent container's instance or null in `attachToRoot` param.

**From link:**

```
Button button = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_button, mLinearLayout, false);
mLinearLayout.addView(button);
```

> By passing in false, we say that we do not want to attach our View to the root
>   ViewGroup just yet. We are saying that it will happen at some other
>   point in time. In this example, the other point in time is simply the
>   addView() method used immediately below inflation.

So if you inflate with:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_fragment, container);
```

First it will immediately attach `confirm_fragment` to container. After returning the view, fragment will be tried to be added to parent again implicitly, but since it has been added already, exception will be thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Hope you got the point.

Answer (score 1):

> where did I specify a parent for the view [...] ?

You add a `Fragment` dynamically by writing something like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(android.R.id.content, myFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

In `add()`, you specify where the `Fragment` should be displayed (in this case fullscreen) by passing the id of the desired container.

See also the method description in the reference [developers.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)):

> containerViewId    int: Optional identifier of the container this fragment is to be placed in. If 0, it will not be placed in a container.

I you don't add a `Fragment` to the UI (e.g. you need it for caching purposes as a retained fragment), `onCreateView()` will  never be called.

So once `onCreateView()` is called, the parent for this `Fragment` already exists - the `FragmentManager` set it for you.

Comment: Yeah I did it like this. So the add method automatically sets the parent?

Comment: @VaibhavSharma - yes, it does. I added a link to documentation (developer.android.com)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `attachToParent` to `false`
Example:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_fragment, container,false);
```

Comment: yeah if I specify my container as null as I did in my answer, it passes attachtoroot as false.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: yeah if I specify my container as null as I did in my answer, it passes attachtoroot as false.